# Shadow between NSViews

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I am currently working on an app which displays a subview with a progress control when it's doing some work. The subview appears from the top of the window using animation, and hides back when the operation is finished.

It looks like this (sorry, can't post images yet):
 [screenshot: view without shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBB2p.png)

what i would like, is to make a drop shadow between those views, to make it looks like if the progress windows is just over the list view, not just above it.
It's difficult to explain. It would be something like this:

[screenshot: progress view with drop shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xxbn.png)
I really don't know how could i get that effect using cocoa.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Use `-[NSView setShadow:]`. See the [NSView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) for full info.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I already looked that, But in order to setShadow to work, i must enable layers for that view. I wouldn't like to do that, because it affects the way text is rendered (no antialiasing)

Comment: I believe you can get subpixel antialiasing with layer-backed views. You just have to make sure it knows its background (since you can't antialias on an unknown background). See this thread on the topic: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/202561-catextlayer-and-subpixel-anti-aliasing.html#202581

Comment: Great. I will look into it. Thank you both for the answers